# Unit test always passed even with false assertions values on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, junit, junit4

Unit test always passed even with false assertions values on Android Studio, for example when writing this method it passed

```
 @Test
    fun testAssert(){
    assertEquals(1,2)
    }
```

[image]

I don't know why this happens and I checked my test configuration if it has a problem but I think there is no problem
[image]

And here the full build print on running the test

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\idea_rt.jar=53441:C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Amin\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath152820636.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 (package.....).ApiServiceTest,testAssert
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

on using gradle/app:test in terminal I got this

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see TBD.
To determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:
4.12.0'.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
90 actionable tasks: 90 up-to-date
```

Comment: Are you getting the same result while running tests via gradle?

Comment: @deepakchethan I follow this instruction to test via gradle from this link https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint so I write /gradlew app:test in android studio terminal but it won't open the run for my tests it just checks my project and gives me some warning messages

Comment: @deepakchethan I updated my question with what I got

Comment: Can you try with `./gradlew test` ? Check [https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line)

Comment: @deepakchethan I tried also it wouldn't help, the terminal finish the build and it didn't give any info about test or moves to run view to check it inside?

Comment: here a video record of what happened https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1522ab64266179db36dd482e3148af4320210608112050/ab2f78

Comment: Can you also share the imports used and gradle dependencies? Please confirm if its only in this project or others also?

Comment: I found the problem in the MainCoroutineRule used for setup before the test, thanks too much for your trying to help